# Artificial Gravity

Tags: science-based, space-travel, spaceships, spacetime-dimensions

What is a push field gravity generator?  An interstellar vessel traveling at near light speed how would the crew in science fiction generate artificial gravity?  Not using the typical rotation rings to generate centrifugal forces.

Comment: We only know 2 ways to generate gravity: real gravity via mass, apparent gravity via constant acceleration (either linear or rotational). To me it is totally unclear what are you asking

Comment: It is likely that you are reading John Scalzi's latest novel *The End of all Things*. In that case a push-field-generator is a piece of fancy non-existant technology that pushes people down instead of pulling them like *normal* scifi artificial gravity solutions work...

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible methods for a hypothetical Gravitational Drive that an advanced, Interstellar Travel capable civilization can implement for Artificial Gravity Generation without any rotational or linear motion:

1. [EMRP Push Gravitaional Field](http://www.blazelabs.com/f-g-intro.asp) (as you vaguely mentioned)
2. [Graviton Particle Field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graviton)

EMRP, or Electro-Magnetic Radiation Pressure Push Gravitational Field, is actually a theory that kind of extends Einstein's general Theory of relativity. It says that gravity is caused by Cosmic Electro-Magnetic Radiation, which keeps cosmic objects held together. The Vessel can have some generator which either amplifies this field or generates it all together.

Gravitons are hypothetical particles in Theoretical Physics, which are considered to be a source of gravitational force.

> In theoretical physics, the graviton is a hypothetical elementary particle that mediates the force of gravitation in the framework of quantum field theory.

Again, The Vessel can have a generator that can generate this field or amplify it in a certain area of The Vessel.

Comment: See [this answer](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/63310/could-graviton-cushions-theoretically-be-used-for-deceleration/63319#63319) for more on gravitons.